# how to give shadow at bottom with color white in IE 8?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

```
 .divClassGreen
    {      
           box-shadow: 0 0px black inset, 0 -3px white inset, -0px 0 blue inset, 0px 0 green inset;
           border-bottom:5px solid  green;       
    }
```

I want to give shadow white to a tab and border green , this code is working in google chrome and firefox fine. But in IE only border-bottom is working, box - shadow is not working , bascially i am trying to give it two borders, and my elements are get created in c#.

Comment: IE what? 9 is quite a bit different that 6

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is not supported directly in IE8 , you can use box-shadow, but with a little different approach.

Take a look at the codes in this [link](http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/),
and you will see a shadow on IE8 browser.

Also, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to manage cross browser support for shadows etc.

CSS3 Pie supports box-shadow http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Answer (score 0):

more CSS-3 codes work for IE-9 and Higher..

for IE-8 you can just set border to your element:

Answer (score 0):

box-shadow is not supported by ie, try use an image (png) as background targeting ie

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and less have a proprietary `filter` property, this one mimicks the simplest linear gradient: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,000000+100;Custom
in case it's this sort of fallback you'd prefer. But @Aleks answer is probably closer to what you're trying to achieve ;)

Note: if bold/italic text suddenly get blurry and ugly on lesser IEs, blame `filter`!

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using box-shadow as a CSS property in your Internet Explorer 9 and the box-shadow does not show you might want to check if:
You’re using the right syntaxys – you can check if the property appears in the developers window (F12) for the current element.
If this does not help you might want to know, that box-shadow is supported for Internet Explorer 9+, so if you are using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

in your page with Internet Explorer 9 or if you are using Internet Explorer 8 (or lower) box-shadow will not work.
If you want a similar effect in Internet Explorer 8 read this article.

Look below aption

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/